# Request Window Feature from another class

Tags: android, title

I want the screen set to (Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE). I know that I can put requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); in the OnCreate method but I have another Class let's say Class B which is extended to the Fragment and it has a button in the layout. I want when that button is clicked in clicked in Class B, the Window should be shown without the Title. I tried as below:

```
AnandSahib anad = new AnandSahib();
anad.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you cant do it.you should call anad.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); before setContentView().please See this [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#requestFeature%28int%29)

Comment: In that case, is there any other way I can maximize the screen layout?

Comment: I think dont exist any way for hide and show title bar after finish oncreate() method.but you can have a layout as title bar yourself and hide and show any time you want